# Deep linking into a storyboard with the correct backstack

Tags: ios

I would like to create a "deep link" into my storyboard while preserving the backstack (back button navigation).

Ex:

Given the storyboard below (entry point being the leftmost Navigation controller)

[image: storyboard]

When my application is opened via a remote notification I would like to open the second tab in by tab controller AND be able to navigate back to the item list via the back button.

Please note that I am not asking about how to open the second tab, or how to create such a storyboard but specifically if there is a way to do this with storyboards or will I have to do it by code.

Thanks!

PS: I come from an Android background where one recreates the parent view controller manually or (better) inserts it into the backstack. As far as my research goes there is no such thing in ios. I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UINavigationController` has a [`viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) property.  You can create as many view controllers as you want in an `NSArray` and assign it to this property and that will be the back stack with the last VC in the array displayed.

Comment: A subquestion: how would I animate the change? I tried pushViewC(animate:true), but that goes through all the view controllers added, which is not what I want. Im thinking the correct choice would be to do something with the window instead of view controllers.

That somewhat works, thanks. The problem is that the parent navigationController with its navigationBar does not track the changes and when the user navigates back title transitions are not smooth, they are offset by a bit. Its hard to describe. 

I used pushViewController to create the "back stack" and that worked better.

Comment: You could set the back stack with n-1 items, the pushVC(animated:true) on the nth VC?

Comment: I tried that, it jump to the "back stack" and than animates tho the last vc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when a notification arrives, your app could be in any state at all. It could be running, with some other screen showing. It could be suspended, with some other screen showing. Or it might not be running at all, and will now have to be launched from scratch.

Thus, starting in the App Delegate routine that responds here, you will have to deal manually (in code) with the situation if you want to put your app into an appropriate state.